# Merge [anko] and [kotlin-anko]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The reason for this request lies in having two tags with the exact same meaning, but at two different locations. [anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anko) refers to the same library as [kotlin-anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-anko). There is also only one library called Anko at the moment (as far as I know), and that is the Kotlin library used with Android ([for context, it's this one](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)).

The `kotlin-anko` tag does not have a wiki, but the `anko` tag does:

> Anko is JetBrains library for Android application development (wrapper for Android SDK for Java), written in [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin).

There's also [65 questions with both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Banko%5D%5Bkotlin-anko%5D&mixed=0).

Given that these two tags are meant for the same library, these tags should be merged. I also suggest using [kotlin-anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-anko) over [anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anko) (to avoid overlap with other libraries, frameworks, or similar if one with the same name appears later), although [anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anko) as the most questions on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the questions of [kotlin-anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-anko) and most of them were already tagged with [anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anko) (some 23 weren't), and all of them were using the tag correctly.

I also checked the other way round. Looks like there were just 2 [anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anko) questions that were not tagged with the [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) or with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), and even those were related to kotlin anko. So it was very clear that they both are the same tag.

I merged the tags and added [kotlin-anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-anko) as a synonym, so that it won't be recreated.